# reading deflated data from the stream using inflater and InflaterInputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send a deflated string over http, when I use compression and decompression on the server side, without using streams, it's ok but when I write it to stream like this:

```
          byte[] deflatedData = mtext.getByte();
          try {
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200,deflatedData.length);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                display(e1);
                e1.printStackTrace();
                if(closeafter){
                    t.close();
                }
                return;
            }
                DeflaterOutputStream os = new DeflaterOutputStream(t.getResponseBody());
          try {
            os.write(deflatedData ,0,deflatedData .length);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            mByte = null;
            display(e1);
            if(closeafter){
                t.close();
            }
            return;
        }

            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

and read from client side like this:

```
 InflaterInputStream ini = new     
 InflaterInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout =new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
        int b;
        while ((b = ini.read()) != -1) {
              bout.write(b);
        }
        ini.close();
        bout.close();

        String s=new String(bout.toByteArray());
```

android decompresses like this:

```
 public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException{  
       Inflater inflater = new Inflater();   
       inflater.setInput(data);  

       ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);  
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
       while (!inflater.finished()) {  
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);  
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
       }  

       byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();  
       outputStream.close();  
       inflater.end();

       return output;  
      }
```

so I get the following exception:

```
  java.util.zip.DataFormatException: data error
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you inflating twice?

Comment: first one is in server ,that is deflating , second one is in client

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. If you're deflati/inflating in both directions you should certainyl use the same code to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The sending part was totally ok , The answer was to Use InflaterInputStream Directly from the input stream , like this:

```
 public static String ReadDeflatedData(InputStream input){

    InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(input, new Inflater());

    int bytesRead=0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] contents = null;
    try {
        contents = new byte[in.available()];
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        while( (bytesRead = in.read(contents)) != -1){

              sb.append(new String(contents, 0, bytesRead));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        return new String(sb.toString().getBytes(),"UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question either. If there was an error upstream of the code you posted, you should show it here.